# How to sort individual column values in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to sort each column value alphabetically, independently of other values.

```
a_string = "hgfedcba"

sorted_characters = sorted(a_string)

a_string = "".join(sorted_characters)

print(a_string)
```

Ouput: abcdefgh

I am trying to apply this same concept to an entire column of a dataframe for each value:

```
for name in df['OTHER_NAME']:
    df['names_sorted'] = ''.join(sorted(name))
    
df['names_sorted']
```

Output:
0      EEEIKLZ
1      EEEIKLZ
2      EEEIKLZ
3      EEEIKLZ
4      EEEIKLZ

The problem I am running into is that it's returning the same name for each row when each row should be different.

Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Use [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html#pandas.Series.sort_values)

Comment: That sorts the values with respect to other values within the series. I am looking to sort each value of the series alphabetically on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply the function to each row just use `DataFrame.apply()` with a lambda function:

```
df['names_sorted'] = df['OTHER_NAME'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(sorted(x)))
```

Comment: Ahh thats how you do it. Thank you very much